# R: is there an equivalent of diff(x) for dividing?

Tags: r, diff

I am working with dataframes of financial data where I want to take the difference between rows, and also the "change" between rows. For the difference, the task is easy, simply:

```
apply(df, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) diff(x))
```

My problem occurs when I want to have the change instead of the difference. That is, in each column of the data frame, I want to iteratively take the next element of the column divided by the previous and subtract one. My quick and dirty way of doing this is the following:

```
apply(df, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) x[2:length(x)]/x[1:length(x)-1]-1)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a function that would do this for me?

**EDIT**: small reproducible, as requested:

data<-data.frame(c(1,2,4,15),c(2,1,5,8))

[image: data]

output from my own code snippet above (also what is expected):

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a base R function that does exactly this but there are different `lag`/`lead` functions in external packages. For example, you can use `dplyr` like this:

```
> mutate_each(head(iris[-5]), funs(./lag(.)-1))
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1           NA          NA           NA          NA
#2  -0.03921569 -0.14285714   0.00000000           0
#3  -0.04081633  0.06666667  -0.07142857           0
#4  -0.02127660 -0.03125000   0.15384615           0
#5   0.08695652  0.16129032  -0.06666667           0
#6   0.08000000  0.08333333   0.21428571           1
```

Compared to your own function:

```
> apply(head(iris[-5]), MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) x[2:length(x)]/x[1:length(x)-1]-1)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#2  -0.03921569 -0.14285714   0.00000000           0
#3  -0.04081633  0.06666667  -0.07142857           0
#4  -0.02127660 -0.03125000   0.15384615           0
#5   0.08695652  0.16129032  -0.06666667           0
#6   0.08000000  0.08333333   0.21428571           1
```

You can put that in a custom function and use that:

```
f <- function(., n = 1L, default = NA) ./dplyr::lag(., n = n, default = default) -1
mutate_each(head(iris[-5]), funs(f))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(head(iris))[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
                  x/shift(x)-1), .SDcols=1:4]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1:           NA          NA           NA          NA
#2:  -0.03921569 -0.14285714   0.00000000           0
#3:  -0.04081633  0.06666667  -0.07142857           0
#4:  -0.02127660 -0.03125000   0.15384615           0
#5:   0.08695652  0.16129032  -0.06666667           0
#6:   0.08000000  0.08333333   0.21428571           1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ways. The first returns a data frame, the second a matrix and the last a zoo object.  The first two do not use any packages.

```
> data[-1,] / data[-nrow(data), ] - 1
  c.1..2..4..15. c.2..1..5..8.
2           1.00          -0.5
3           1.00           4.0
4           2.75           0.6

> exp(diff(log(as.matrix(data)))) - 1
     c.1..2..4..15. c.2..1..5..8.
[1,]           1.00          -0.5
[2,]           1.00           4.0
[3,]           2.75           0.6

> library(zoo)
> diff(as.zoo(data), arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
  c.1..2..4..15. c.2..1..5..8.
2           1.00          -0.5
3           1.00           4.0
4           2.75           0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a log transformation `exp(diff(log(x)))-1)`:

```
> apply(data, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) exp(diff(log(x)))-1)
     c.1..2..4..15. c.2..1..5..8.
[1,]           1.00          -0.5
[2,]           1.00           4.0
[3,]           2.75           0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way:

```
x <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
x/lag(x)

# [1] NA 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000
```